# How can I know which machine Juju is actually using?

Tags: juju

I am trying Juju on Azure and I have installed quite a few services that I have now destroyed to keep only the minimum services. But now I can see I have 8 virtual machines created on Azure while I have reduced the number of services to just 4. So I guess when Juju needs a new machine it creates it but then destroying the service did not destroy the machine it was running on.
How can I do some cleanup? I would like to know which machines are unused and destroy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a `juju status` will show you all the machines running. It depends on which commands you run:

```
juju destroy-service <service-name>
```

will destroy only the service. You probably want either:

```
juju destroy-unit
```

or

```
juju destroy-machine
```

To clean up what you have you probably can do a `juju status`, see which machines are not assigned to services, and then destroy those by referrring them by number, like: `juju destroy-machine 3` as an example.

All of these are documented here:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-destroy

Comment: thanks the command line makes sense indeed, I destroyed them in the GUI without knowing what was going on underneath.

Comment: Huh, and the GUI left the machines over?

Comment: well apparently yes, I'm no expert yet so take my words with caution but I clicked the 'destroy' button, the service disappeared and in juju status I can see all the machines.

Comment: something interesting from the docs: 'To prevent accidents and awkward moments with running services, it is not possible to remove an instance which is currently allocated to a service.' So I can go ahead and try to destroy everything, only the machines that can be safely destroyed will be affected.

Comment: ouch I did not even realize the juju status gives the corresponding machine number of every service :)

Comment: Hey can you send me a mail (It's in my profile info) - I can get the web UI guys on and we can talk about how we can improve this experience - it's critical that we don't confuse users about how many machines are actually running, that can cost a lot of money!

Comment: happy to contribute, it should be in your inbox by now.